# Treat value of string as .. an attribute name?

Tags: python

Say I have a `dict`:

```
d = {
    'eggs': 4,
    'cheese': 6,
    'coconuts': 8,
}
```

Is is possible to loop over the dictionary, creating variables named after the keys, assigning them the corresponding value?

```
eggs = 4
cheese = 6
coconuts = 8
```

Or maybe inside an object?

```
self.eggs = 4
self.cheese = 6
self.coconuts = 8
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you already have them in a dict, why do you need them as variables? Just curious.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Advisable, acceptable, a good idea? Most propably no. Why would you want/need this?

Comment: Explaining "why" is material for a separate question. Later today, possibly. So for now, please slap a huge "not-advisable" sticker on it, if you must, but I'd still like to know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> d = {
...     'eggs': 4,
...     'cheese': 6,
...     'coconuts': 8,
... }
>>> globals().update(d)
>>> eggs
4
>>> cheese
6
>>> coconuts
8
>>> d
{'cheese': 6, 'eggs': 4, 'coconuts': 8}
```

But for classes, it is easier(safer), just use:

```
for item, value in d.items():
     setattr(some_object, item, value) #or self.setattr(item, value)
```

Comment: I used this method for a script in my job. This perl guy saw it and said "now I know you can write one line of python, and screw up the readability of an entire module"

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Alex Martelli's Bunch class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/):

```
>>> class Bunch(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwds):
...         self.__dict__.update(kwds)
...
>>> d = {
...     'eggs': 4,
...     'cheese': 6,
...     'coconuts': 8,
... }
>>> b = Bunch(**d)
>>> b.eggs
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use setattr:

```
d = {
    'eggs': 4,
    'cheese': 6,
    'coconuts': 8,
}

class Food: pass

food = Food()

for item in d.iteritems():
    setattr(food, *item)

print(food.eggs, food.cheese, food.coconuts)
```

Comment: `setattr(food, *item)` was interesting (+1).